# Magento admin page completely blank, no errors to be found anywhere

Tags: php, apache, magento

The problem started a while ago, but at the time there were other priorities and it's now hard to trace back any system changes than might have caused it. In short, going to http://mysite/index.php/admin/ provides me with a blank page. As in 0 bytes.

The code of index.php page starts with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Memory limit set in php.ini is 512MB. I have done `chmod -R 777 *` in Magento's top directory and I just fail to see any clues as to what could be causing it to give me a blank page. The store front of this Magento installation works properly. What can I do to figure this out?

Edit: I tried removing cache as well, to no avail.

Comment: you shouldnot chmod php files with 777, all the php files should be chmodded to 644 and the directories should be chmodded to 755. and .htaccess should be chmodded to 666

Comment: sure, in principle 777 is too permissive, but it's not going to cause this kind of issue to happen. on the other hand, depending on the setup insufficient permissions may cause scripts to halt. so modding them 777 is just a quick check to verify that it's not a problem of insufficient permissions.

Comment: Is there anything in your Magento or Apache logs? Do you have any modules other than core installed?

Comment: Turns out someone added an IP based filter to one of the included files, so when accessing the site from an unapproved IP address it would just die(). That's what happens when you don't do proper version control ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable magento error reporting by renaming "magento/errors/local.xml.sample" to "magento/errors/local.xml". This may give you some hints to trace your problem.